# Invisible name when selecting new record type

Tags: model, typo3, backend, extbase

I'm developing a typo 3 extension and i had to add a new model recently.
I did so using the kickstarter, but somehow the name is invisible when i want to select it as a new record (it does show the icon tho):
[image: Invisible name]
When i select it the name is still weird in the backend. As if it didn't save the name correctly. Looks like this:
[image]
Instead of `tx_collectionpl...` it should say just `"Plan"`

Do i have to register the name somwhere? I've lloked through various files alredy but couldnt find anything (the ones that alredy existed are being shown properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name come from the `title` property in the `conf` section of the `TCA (Table Configuration Array)` provided by your extension, most likely in the `ext_tables.php` file.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#title